# Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, build

I just updated the Android Studio to 3.5.0 and I'm getting
 Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted . Message while the build is running. Also, the build is taking more time to complete. Does anyone have any idea regarding this error help me?

Comment: I had the same error and I read a lot of doc on the internet but I didn't find any solution for this, I was forced to remove and install again all things in  my computer

Comment: In windows, You can add a system environment variable named _JAVA_OPTIONS, and set the heap size values there.Like this SET _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms512m -Xmx1024m

Comment: try a system restart after @ViralPatel 's suggestion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you add more modules to your app, there is an incredible demand placed on the Android build system, and the default memory settings will not work. To avoid OutOfMemoryErrors during Android builds, you should uncomment the alternate gradle memory setting present in /android/gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Not sure if this works with Gradle 7 and above.

Answer (score 53):

I had the same problem, and the following answer helped but needs to be adapted to React Native.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548822/6798074

Make your `gradle.properties` look like the following:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

And add the following in your `app/build.gradle` under the android task:

```
android {

  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying  couple of solution below code finally resolve the error

Add below in `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1028m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
1)
Add following in android/app/build.gradle:

```
android: {
...
   dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize: "4g"
   }
}
```

2. 

Add following in android/gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

Comment: You need to use 
    
   `dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }`

instead

    You need to use `dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize: "4g"
   }`

Notice: colon (:) is not there. Otherwise, you'll get an error `In case you tried to configure a property named 'javaMaxHeapSize', replace ':' with '=' or ' ', otherwise it will not have the desired effect.`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in `gradle-wrapper-properties`

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

here -Xmx4g will provide dex size to 4Gb, same as javaMaxHeapSize.  XX:MaxPermSize is the permanent heap size to allocate.