# react-native-plaid-link-sdk Error: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: android, react-native

Thanks for heaving a look at the issue u am facing. Basically I am trying to integrate plaid into my react-native's android application using `react-native-plaid-link-sdk`. I am getting the following error on running `npx react-native run-android`

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-plaid-link-sdk:compileDebugKotlin'.

I have opened an issue on their github repo as well. Please have a look [there](https://github.com/plaid/react-native-plaid-link-sdk/issues/392) for more error logs.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anyone out there facing the same issue, you'll need to update you're Kotlin version (or define it if it wasn't previously as was my case) in
`android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    // other stuff
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10'
       // other stuff
    }
}
```

thanks to the solution poster [here](https://github.com/plaid/react-native-plaid-link-sdk/issues/392#issuecomment-868857758)

Comment: After this, I also needed to increase my java heap size:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075455/expiring-daemon-because-jvm-heap-space-is-exhausted