# Error Building APK build Error> Task :app:packageRelease FAILED

Tags: gradle, react-native, apk

I am trying to generate android APK build, and I am getting different errors every time, from different libraries
for example here it says `> Task :react-native-fast-image:mergeReleaseResources  FAILED`
[image]

after that I didn't do anything I just re-run `./gradlew  clean` &&  `./gradlew assembleRelease` and it shows me different error

[image]

and I am in the loop since yesterday, any clue what's the problem or maybe solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by configuring the max heap size for your project.

Add this to your android/gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560m
```

For more options prefer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075455/expiring-daemon-because-jvm-heap-space-is-exhausted).