# React Native Android Bundle Release Hangs on :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease

Tags: android, react-native

Running `react-native run-android` and `react-native run-android --variant=release`, the app builds and runs fine on an Android device. iOS build and release also works fine for that matter. I have followed the [signing instructions here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android).

When I run `./gradlew bundleRelease` the first few tasks finish successfully fairly quickly but the process hangs on `:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease`. It has been executing for over an hour. Below is the full log. I'm not sure how to debug this best. Are there any flags I can add to the command?

```
> Configure project :app
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getAssemble(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessManifest(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getMergeAssets(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getPackageApplication(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
WARNING: API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :lottie-react-native
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.

> Configure project :react-native-cookies
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from /Users/davidadler/Projects/app/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-webview
:react-native-webview:reactNativeAndroidRoot /Users/davidadler/Projects/app/node_modules/react-native/android

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/davidadler/Projects/app/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 22 asset files
info Done copying assets

> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/davidadler/Projects/app/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:generateBundledResourcesHashRelease
03a478725b08cbc57d0ab5d9fb1cc3a78e325c451b00efcc325a1b5deb1e79e9
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [10m 0s]
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [10m 0s]rForRelease
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [10m 0s]rForRelease
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [10m 1s]rForRelease
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [10m 1s]rForRelease
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [10m 1s]rForRelease
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [44m 51s]
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [44m 51s]ForRelease
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [44m 51s]ForRelease
<==========---> 79% EXECUTING [45m 4s]
> :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, I'm trying to update our app from 0.59.2 to 0.59.9

It seems to have solved it by adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -XX\:MaxHeapSize\=32g` to `android/gradle.properties` - As referring to this answer [Gradle build of Android app in VSTS failing after running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207126/gradle-build-of-android-app-in-vsts-failing-after-running-out-of-memory)

Moreover, I also have this in the `android` section of `android/app/build.gradle`

```
android {
  ...
  ...
  dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```